# Missing Data When Importing from Folder

Tags: r

I encountered loss of data while importing from folder. Most of the information is present but irrelevant without the missing ones. The code is still at its early stage and no input suggests the information has been removed. In fact it is just a simple extract from folder (see below).

let

```
    Source = Folder.Files("File"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Extension], ".xls")),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File from Export from PDF", each #"Transform File from Export from PDF"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File from Export from PDF"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File from Export from PDF", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File from Export from PDF"(#"Sample File")))
in
    #"Expanded Table Column1"
```

Comment: What package are you using? I'm not familiar with `Folder.Files()` function, does it know how to interpret all those commented rows?

Comment: My impression is that this is not actually R code, I'm not sure what language it would be though.